# SSH Public Key Authentication not working with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-keys, public-key

I have created a virtual machine and installed Redhat 6. I am having issues connecting using public key authentication.

I can use PuTTY on my Windows host to connect to the redhat guest, where I am prompted for a password. I am trying to setup public-key authentication for the root user, so I have created a folder `~/.ssh` with what I believe to be the correct permissions.

```
[root@redhat ~]# cd ~/.ssh
[root@redhat .ssh]# pwd
/root/.ssh
[root@redhat .ssh]# ls -la
total 16
drwx------. 2 root root 4096 Aug 21 16:28 .
dr-x------. 3 root root 4096 Aug 20 17:20 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  250 Aug 20 17:20 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  391 Aug 21 16:28 known_hosts
```

I am running Pageant with my private key loaded, this is working successfully with other hosts, so I don't think that's the problem.

When I attempt to PuTTY to the VM guest, I am getting prompted for a password.

If I check the PuTTY Event Log, I find the following messages.

```
2012-08-21 17:29:41 Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
2012-08-21 17:29:41 Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
2012-08-21 17:29:46 Trying Pageant key #0
2012-08-21 17:29:46 Server refused our key
```

I have Agent forwarding enabled, and one thing I stumbled across was somebody suggested running another copy of sshd in debug mode, which I tried. (I have snipped out portions of the output to keep this somewhat brief).

```
[root@redhat ~]# /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.3p1
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
<...>
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
<...>
```

At this point I connect from another session on the vm using the command `ssh localhost -p 2222`

```
<...>
Connection from ::1 port 36844
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
<...>
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "localhost"
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: <snip>
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for root from ::1 port 36844 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 2 failures 0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1
Found matching RSA key: <snip>
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted publickey for root from ::1 port 36844 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: root has been authenticated by privileged process
<...>
```

At this point I have authenticated sucessfully using my public key, and I logout by pressing `Ctrl-D`.

```
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
<...>
Received disconnect from ::1: 11: disconnected by user
<...>
[root@redhat ~]#
```

So strangely using the SSH Agent forwarding was enough to successfully authenticate against sshd running in debug mode, but not the 'normal' sshd running on port 22.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SELinux contexts on your `/root/.ssh` directory are most likely wrong.

Verify the problem with:

```
ls -alZ /root/.ssh
```

These files should have the type `ssh_home_t`.

Fix the problem with:

```
restorecon -r -v /root/.ssh
```